# How to add parentheses between numbers? I know how to add dashes, are they doing the same way?

Tags: r, parentheses

how to add parentheses between numbers? I know how to add dashes, are they doing the same way? like 123456789 to (123)456789 in R programming?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll have to provide more details. Are the parentheses added always at the 1st and 4th character? Is there any other logic to follow? What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub("(\\d{3})", "(\\1)", 123456789)
[1] "(123)456789"
```